# MySql: Upload CSV data into Temporary Table and Then join

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, join, inner-join

I am facing a very weird problem with Mysql query. I am not sure if I am doing it right or not. I have tried crawling the web for a legitimate solution but couldn't find anything.

I have 1 table, say something as follow:

**Table Foo**

```
ID | Col1 | Col2
-------------------------
1  | abc  | ABC1234567675
2  | def  | ABC3435345345
```

- ID is of type Int
- Col1 is Varchar(50)
- Col2 is an Alpha numeric string of type varchar(200)

I have a CSV file which has only 1 column, which has same values like Col2 of Foo table above.

I am loading the CSV into the Temporary table, let's say Bar using the queries as follows:

```
drop temporary table Bar;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Bar (
  Col2 varchar(200)
);


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/update.csv'
INTO table Bar;
```

When I do a Select * on the Temp Table Bar. It lists all the values it has uploaded from the CSV into the temp table.

But when i try to join it on Col2. It is returning only 1 result.

Whereas when i manually query the table Foo with a where clause using the Col2 values from the Table Bar. It is showing many records exists in table Foo.

I have tried below queries:

```
select * from Foo inner join Bar on Foo.Col2=Bar.Col2;

select * from Foo join (select Col2 from Bar) b on Foo.Col2=b.Col2;

select * from Foo where Col2 in (select Col2 from Bar);
```

But all three of them returns only 1 result.
Had anyone else also faced similar problem in the past?
Could you guide me to what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check and see if the Col2 in Bar contains any trailing whitespaces. If none, then check the Col2 in Foo.

Comment: I tried with TRIM() function tried trimming both the values in the where clause but didn't worked.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, After a lot of googling I found that my "LOAD DATA" command is not complete. I had Carriage return and Newline characters in the Bar table data. So I had to put below lines in my "Load Data" command:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

And then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/yourfile.csv'
INTO table name;"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).